# Airplay http requests

Tags: curl, google-chrome-devtools, airplay

I'm trying to build an android controler for an airplay receiver (contained in a tv mediaplayer).

I'm using curl for testing the request and also [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm), a chrome extension which  builds http requests.
The requests are well understood by the server if I use postman, but I must not reproduce the request with curl.

For example, a request which asks the current position for the media currently played:

```
curl -i \
192.168.1.42:7000/scrub \
-H "Connection: keep-alive" \
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31" \
-H "Accept: */*" \
-H "Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" \
-H "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" \
```

returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/parameters
Content-Length: 38

duration: 0.000000
position: 0.000000
```

while postman returns the correct values:

```
duration: 275.838989
position: 13.000000
```

The headers used in the curl request come from the request made with postman using the dev-tools of Chrome.

So, is there any difference in the request in Chrome between the request effectively sent and what I see in the dev-tools? The problem could certainly come from elsewhere, as it make no sense for me that curl cannot reproduce the same response.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

- Check the result of curl with -v to see what headers you are passing from the command line.   Ensure that everything matches up with the headers being sent via postman
- Check if the host is setting cookies (tab in postman).  If it is, try enabling cookies on your curl request with the -b option http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Comment: yes, the request headers are correct, I even used wireshard to see the raw request. There's no cookies.

Comment: I've found! The requests have to be made on the same tcp stream.